# How do I form a MS SQL Server SELECT Statement to Fill a specific VIEW with EMPTY string, based on a condition

Tags: sql-server, datetime, select

Firstly, thank you in advance to EVERYONE who takes the answers this question.

I have a simple SQL Server view (on an existing table) in SQL Server 2012 Express. The view has two columns of interest, for (printed) reporting purposes.

Both columns are of datatype `DATETIME`. One is for `Departure` date-time, the other `Arrival` date-time.

Now, my questions is this folks. What would be the `SELECT` clause syntax, so that if either of the datetime columns does not equate to today, the view can create a new column as a blank string?

So, for instance, if `ArrivalDate` is not equal to today, I wish to not just return that date stored in `ArrivalDate`, **but a BLANK string.**

I have included the `SELECT` statement for the view as it stands now:

```
SELECT    
    bookingRef, custName, departureDateTime, arrivalDateTime
FROM      
    dbo.Bookings
WHERE     
    (departureDateTime BETWEEN CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) 
    AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))) 
    OR (arrivalDateTime BETWEEN CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) 
    AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)))
```

Am I right in remembering that this task requires variables/parametric utilization???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right first of all  String datatypes can have Empty strings but Date datatype cannot have empty date values, It can have either a date value or `NULL` value.

You can either return a dummy date like 1900-01-01 or NULL. but you cannot have an empty string in a datetime/date column.

Therefore you can do something like this...

```
SELECT    bookingRef
        , custName
        , CASE WHEN CAST(departureDateTime AS DATE) <> CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
                 THEN NULL
               ELSE departureDateTime END AS departureDateTime 
        , CASE WHEN CAST(arrivalDateTime AS DATE) <> CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
                  THEN NULL
               ELSE arrivalDateTime END AS arrivalDateTime
FROM      dbo.Bookings
WHERE CAST(departureDateTime AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
  OR  CAST(arrivalDateTime AS DATE)   = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Or you can have the datetime column returned in string/character datatype, then you can have empty strings in your final result. you could do something like this...

```
SELECT    bookingRef
        , custName
        , CASE WHEN CAST(departureDateTime AS DATE) <> CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
                 THEN ''
               ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), departureDateTime, 120) 
                 END AS departureDateTime 
        , CASE WHEN CAST(arrivalDateTime AS DATE) <> CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
                  THEN ''
               ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), arrivalDateTime, 120)
                END AS arrivalDateTime
FROM      dbo.Bookings
WHERE CAST(departureDateTime AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
  OR  CAST(arrivalDateTime AS DATE)   = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Comment: Forgive me, I think my question wasn't posed correctly. :) The returning of the NULL part I understand(I am from a C++ background). But , the VIEW now returns ALL rows in the table, instead of ONLY rows that have EITHER departureDateTime OR arrivalDateTime that equate to today.

Comment: Thank you M.Ali. :) I managed to add back the WHERE clause and use your CASE conditional-statement, to get what I wanted. Well done! and Thank YOU!

Comment: I thought you wanted return all the rows and just replace them with empty strings if the date wasnt equal to todays's date I have added back today's date. Not a problem glad to help :)

Comment: Very impressed with your level of knowledge of SQL syntax. Awesome! Thank you.

Comment: A person with C++ background will find t-sql a child's play sir :) your welcome, glad to help

Comment: I know, but the last time I did any DB related coding was 15  years ago.(been stuck in the world of embedded /hardware  projects where SQLite is the closest we get to an RDBMS! LOL ) . Anyway, MS keep "improving" their SQL products and syntax all the time and I get lost in all their "Microsoft specific" syntax and semantics. :) Thank you again. Wonderful to be helped by someone like you. [bows]